# Canonical way to select columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am comparing common "tidying" operations in dplyr and in "plain R" (see the [output here](https://rawgit.com/ahdxb/datasciencecoursera/master/notes/Notes_on_dplyr.html) and [source here](https://github.com/ahdxb/datasciencecoursera/blob/master/notes/Notes%20on%20dplyr.Rmd) to see what I mean).

I have a hard time finding a "canonical" *and concise* way to select columns using only variable names (by canonical, I mean, pure plain R and easily understandable for anyone with minimum understanding of R (so no "voodoo trick")).

Example:

```
## subset: all columns from "var_1" to "var_2" excluding "var_3"

## dplyr: 
table %>% select(var_1:var_2, -var_3)

## plain R: 
r <- sapply(c("var_1", "var_2", "var_3"), function(x) which(names(table)==x))
table[ ,setdiff(r[1]:r[2],r[3]) ]
```

Any suggestions to improve the plain R syntax?

---

Edit

I implemented some suggestions and compared performance over different syntaxes, and noticed the use of `match` and `subset` lead to surprising falls in performance:

```
# plain R, v1
system.time(for (i in 1:100) { 
    r <- sapply(c("size", "country"), function(x) which(names(cran_df)==x))
    cran_df[,r[1]:r[2]] } )
##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.006   0.000   0.007

# plain R, using match
system.time(for (i in 1:100) { 
    r <- match(c("size", "country"), names(cran_df))
    cran_df[,r[1]:r[2]] %>% head(n=3) } )
##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.056   0.028   0.084

# plain R, using match and subset
system.time(for (i in 1:100) {
    r <- match(c("size", "country"), names(cran_df))
    subset(cran_df, select=r[1]:r[2]) %>% head(n=3) } )
##    user  system elapsed 
##  11.556   1.057  12.640

# dplyr
system.time(for (i in 1:100) select(cran_tbl_df,size:country))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.034   0.000   0.034
```

Looks like the implementation of `subset` is sub-optimal...

Comment: is grepping voodoo? `grep('var_[12]', c('var_1','var_2','var_3'))`

Comment: Note that the `r <-` line could be replaced with `r <- match(c("var_1", "var_2", "var_3"), names(table))`

Comment: @rawr: good question :) it probably isn't although I'm not a big fan (subjective opinion) as it rather looks like an injection from a script lang - thanks for pointing it out though

Comment: @DavidRobinson: thanks for the hint, that's already much clearer and concise

Comment: I don't understand your third test: why would you use both `match` and `subset`? Why wouldn't you just do `subset(cran_df, select=size:country)`?

Comment: Having said that, you're absolutely right about the performance hit on large data frames (on small ones `subset` actually beats `select`) For starters, look at the code `base::subset.data.frame`: if the second argument is missing (which subsets rows), it just creates a vector `rep_len(TRUE, nrow(x))` and uses that to subset the rows: which is a wasteful operation since we're just looking at columns.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: wrt match and subset, I didn't know one could do that (too lazy to read subset's man), I'll amend that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the built in `subset` function, which can take a `select` argument that follows similar (though not identical) syntax to `dplyr::select`. Note that dropping columns has to be done in a second step:

```
t1 <- subset(table, select = var1:var2)
t2 <- subset(t1, select = -var_3)
```

or:

```
subset(subset(table, select = var1:var2), select = -var_3)
```

For example:

```
subset(subset(mtcars, select = c(mpg:wt)), select = -hp)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that - this is probably as good as it gets in plain R